# How to resize text for cv2.putText according to the image size in OpenCV, Python?

Tags: python, opencv

```py
fontScale = 1
fontThickness = 1

# make sure font thickness is an integer, if not, the OpenCV functions that use this may crash
fontThickness = int(fontThickness)

upperLeftTextOriginX = int(imageWidth * 0.05)
upperLeftTextOriginY = int(imageHeight * 0.05)

textSize, baseline = cv2.getTextSize(resultText, fontFace, fontScale, fontThickness)
textSizeWidth, textSizeHeight = textSize

# calculate the lower left origin of the text area based on the text area center, width, and height
lowerLeftTextOriginX = upperLeftTextOriginX
lowerLeftTextOriginY = upperLeftTextOriginY + textSizeHeight

# write the text on the image
cv2.putText(openCVImage, resultText, (lowerLeftTextOriginX, lowerLeftTextOriginY), fontFace, fontScale, Color,
            fontThickness)
```

It seems `fontScale` does not scale text according to the image width and height because the text is almost in the same size for different sized images. So how can I resize the text according to the image size so that all the text could fit in the image?

Comment: Where are you updating the `fontScale`? Please explain what the other variables are.

Comment: Hi, the question is I do not know how to update `fontScale` according to the image size. Thx

Comment: For what image size do you need `fontScale` =1? I'll share the code as soon as you specify this image size (height x width).

Comment: Actually I'm confused about the value of `fontScale`. But from my experiment, I think for 1000*1000 images or bigger, I can make `fontScale=1`

Comment: Did you finally solve the issue? plase share with the community, or say something. Thank you. I have the same problem.

Comment: @Lewis I adopted parthagar's idea. But it does not work perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution that will fit the text inside your rectangle. If your rectangles are of variable width, then you can get the font scale by looping through the potential scales and measuring how much width (in pixels) would your text take. Once you drop below your rectangle width you can retrieve the scale and use it to actually `putText`:

```
def get_optimal_font_scale(text, width):
    for scale in reversed(range(0, 60, 1)):
        textSize = cv.getTextSize(text, fontFace=cv.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, fontScale=scale/10, thickness=1)
        new_width = textSize[0][0]
        if (new_width <= width):
            print(new_width)
            return scale/10
    return 1
```

Comment: isn't the code missing an indentation in the for?

Comment: `range(0,60,1)` includes the value zero, which I believe to be inappropriate for this question. Also, `reversed(range(0,60,1)` is the same as `reversed(range(60))`.  I'm much happier with the output of `range(59,10,-1)` which gives a minimum size of 1

Answer (score 3):

for this worked!

```
scale = 1 # this value can be from 0 to 1 (0,1] to change the size of the text relative to the image
fontScale = min(imageWidth,imageHeight)/(25/scale)
```

just keep in mind that the font type can affect the 25 constant

Answer (score 2):

##### Approach

One way to approach this is to scale the font size proportionally to the size of the image. In my experience, more natural results are obtained when applying this not only to `fontScale`, but also to `thickness`. For example:

```py
import math

import cv2

FONT_SCALE = 2e-3  # Adjust for larger font size in all images
THICKNESS_SCALE = 1e-3  # Adjust for larger thickness in all images

img = cv2.imread("...")
height, width, _ = img.shape

font_scale = min(width, height) * FONT_SCALE
thickness = math.ceil(min(width, height) * THICKNESS_SCALE)
```

##### Example

Let's take [this free-to-use stock photo](https://www.pexels.com/photo/black-suv-beside-grey-auv-crossing-the-pedestrian-line-during-daytime-125514/) as an example. We create two versions of the base image by rescaling to a width of 2000px and 600px (keeping the aspect ratio constant). With the approach above, text looks appropriately sized to the image size in both cases (here shown in an illustrative use case where we label bounding boxes):

**2000px**

[image]

**600px**

[image]

**Full code to reproduce (*but note: input images have to be preprocessed*):**

```py
import math

import cv2

FONT_SCALE = 2e-3  # Adjust for larger font size in all images
THICKNESS_SCALE = 1e-3  # Adjust for larger thickness in all images
TEXT_Y_OFFSET_SCALE = 1e-2  # Adjust for larger Y-offset of text and bounding box

img_width_to_bboxes = {
    2000: [
        {"xywh": [120, 400, 1200, 510], "label": "car"},
        {"xywh": [1080, 420, 790, 340], "label": "car"},
    ],
    600: [
        {"xywh": [35, 120, 360, 155], "label": "car"},
        {"xywh": [325, 130, 235, 95], "label": "car"},
    ],
}


def add_bbox_and_text() -> None:
    for img_width, bboxes in img_width_to_bboxes.items():
        # Base image from https://www.pexels.com/photo/black-suv-beside-grey-auv-crossing-the-pedestrian-line-during-daytime-125514/
        # Two rescaled versions of the base image created with width of 600px and 2000px
        img = cv2.imread(f"pexels-kaique-rocha-125514_{img_width}.jpg")
        height, width, _ = img.shape
        for bbox in bboxes:
            x, y, w, h = bbox["xywh"]
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(
                img,
                bbox["label"],
                (x, y - int(height * TEXT_Y_OFFSET_SCALE)),
                fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX,
                fontScale=min(width, height) * FONT_SCALE,
                thickness=math.ceil(min(width, height) * THICKNESS_SCALE),
                color=(0, 255, 0),
            )
        cv2.imwrite(f"pexels-kaique-rocha-125514_{img_width}_with_text.jpg", img)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    add_bbox_and_text()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take `fontScale = 1` for images with size approximately 1000 x 1000, then this code should scale your font correctly.

```
fontScale = (imageWidth * imageHeight) / (1000 * 1000) # Would work best for almost square images
```

If you are still having any problem, do comment.

Comment: How does this solve the issue? Let's say I have 4K image. According to your suggestion `fontScale = (3840*2160)/(1000*1000)=8.29`. 8.29 is a huge scale

Comment: @theateist Buddy, it actually means `fontscale = (child_width * child_height) / (parent_width * parent_height)` Therefore, if you have 4K parent picture so formula becomes `fontscale = (child_width*child_height)/(3840*2160)`. If the picture has same height and width as parent picture, fontscale results 1

Answer (score 0):

### I implemented a function to find best fitted centered location for text.

Take a look if these codes help you.

```py
def findFontLocate(s_txt, font_face, font_thick, cv_bgd):
    best_scale = 1.0
    bgd_w = cv_bgd.shape[1]
    bgd_h = cv_bgd.shape[0]
    txt_rect_w = 0
    txt_rect_h = 0
    baseline = 0
    for scale in np.arange(1.0, 6.0, 0.2):
        (ret_w, ret_h), tmp_bsl = cv2.getTextSize(
            s_txt, font_face, scale, font_thick)
        tmp_w = ret_w + 2 * font_thick
        tmp_h = ret_h + 2 * font_thick + tmp_bsl
        if tmp_w >= bgd_w or tmp_h >= bgd_h:
            break
        else:
            baseline = tmp_bsl
            txt_rect_w = tmp_w
            txt_rect_h = tmp_h
            best_scale = scale
    lt_x, lt_y = round(bgd_w/2-txt_rect_w/2), round(bgd_h/2-txt_rect_h/2)
    rb_x, rb_y = round(bgd_w/2+txt_rect_w/2), round(bgd_h/2+txt_rect_h/2)-baseline
    return (lt_x, lt_y, rb_x, rb_y), best_scale, baseline
```

> Note that, the function accept four arguments: `s_txt`(string to render), `font_face`, `font_thick` and `cv_bgd`(background image in ndarray format)

---

When you `putText()`, write codes as following:

```py
cv2.putText(
    cv_bgd, s_txt, (lt_x, rb_y), font_face,
    best_scale, (0,0,0), font_thick, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_optimal_font_scale` function as bellow, to adjust font size according to the image size:

```
def get_optimal_font_scale(text, width):

    for scale in reversed(range(0, 60, 1)):
        textSize = cv2.getTextSize(text, fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, fontScale=scale/10, thickness=1)
        new_width = textSize[0][0]
        if (new_width <= width):
            return scale/10
    return 1

fontScale = 3*(img.shape[1]//6)
font_size = get_optimal_font_scale(text, fontScale)
cv2.putText(img, text, org, font, font_size, color, thickness, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

You can change `fontScale` for your image.

Comment: `b_w` is `fontScale`. answer has been edited. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It`s work for me.

```
double calc_scale_rectbox(const char *txt, int box_width, int box_height, 
                          cv::Size &textSize, int &baseline)

{
       if (!txt) return 1.0;
       double scale = 2.0;
       double w_aprx = 0;
       double h_aprx = 0;
       do
       {
           textSize = cv::getTextSize(txt, FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, scale, 2, 
                                      &baseline);
           w_aprx = textSize.width * 100 / box_width;
           h_aprx = textSize.height * 100 / box_height;
           scale -= 0.1;
        } while (w_aprx > 50 || h_aprx > 50);
        return scale;
 }
```

......

```
cv::Size textSize;

int baseline = 0;

double scale = calc_scale_rectbox(win_caption.c_str(), width, 
                                 height, textSize, baseline);

cv::putText(img, win_caption, Point(width / 2 - textSize.width / 2, 
           (height + textSize.height - baseline + 2) / 2), 
            FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, scale, CV_RGB(255, 255, 255), 2);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A simple utility function:

```py
def optimal_font_dims(img, font_scale = 2e-3, thickness_scale = 5e-3):
    h, w, _ = img.shape
    font_scale = min(w, h) * font_scale
    thickness = math.ceil(min(w, h) * thickness_scale)
    return font_scale, thickness
```

Usage:

```py
font_scale, thickness = optimal_font_dims(image)
cv2.putText(image, "LABEL", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, font_scale, (255,0,0), thickness)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a C# implementation:

```
    public static void PutText(Mat mat, Rect rect, double scale, string text)
    {
        var textBound = Cv2.GetTextSize(text, HersheyFonts.HersheySimplex, 1, 1, out int baseline);
        var widthScale = (double)textBound.Width / rect.Width;
        var heightScale = (double)textBound.Height / rect.Height;
        var finalScale = scale / Math.Max(widthScale, heightScale);
        textBound = Cv2.GetTextSize(text, HersheyFonts.HersheySimplex,
            finalScale, 1, out int baselineScaled);
        var widthDiff = rect.Width - textBound.Width;
        var heightDiff = rect.Height - textBound.Height;
        mat.PutText(text, new Point(rect.Left + widthDiff / 2, rect.Bottom - heightDiff / 2),
            HersheyFonts.HersheySimplex, finalScale, Scalar.Black);
    }
```

Where `rect` is the place where text should be painted, `scale` is the scale of the text inside the `rect`. Text is centered inside the given `rect`. For example, `rect` is 100x100 and the text is completely squared. Then it is painted inside the 80x80 rectangle, shifted by 10x10.

Comment: Generally, unless the person posting the question indicates that another language would be helpful, you should limit your answers to the language, and module(s) indicated in the question.

Comment: @moken thanks for noting that. To my excuse I would say that 1) I don't speak Python; 2) my approach does not involve iterations and is accurate. All other answers are either not accurate or iterate through hardcoded values. That's why I've decided to share my solution. It is quite simple to understand even if one doesn't know C#. Once more, sorry for speaking (pun intended:)) in a different language.